# Join two database tables then group the results as subarrays

Tags: php, codeigniter, join, multidimensional-array, grouping

I am having a hard time relating the result set of two database queries. There can be zero or many related rows between my "barang" rows and my "harga" rows.

My CodeIgniter queries look like this:

```
$barang = $this->db
    ->select('pj_barang.*')
    ->where('dihapus', 'tidak')
    ->get('pj_barang')->result_array();

$harga = $this->db
    ->select('pj_detailsupplier.*')
    ->join('pj_barang', 'pj_detailsupplier.id_barang = pj_barang.id_barang', 'right')
    ->get('pj_detailsupplier')
    ->result_array();
```

These queries populate array structures like these (many columns removed for simplicity):

```
$barang=array(
    [
        'id_barang' => 01,
        'nama_barang' => "laptop",
        'merk' => 'lenovo'
    ],
    [
        'id_barang' => 02,
        'nama_barang' => "RAM",
        'merk' => 'lenovo'
    ],
    [
        'id_barang' => 03,
        'nama_barang' => "Keyborad",
        'merk' => 'lenovo'
    ],
);

$harga=array(
    [
        'id_barang' => 01,
        'harga' => 2000000,
    ],
    [
        'id_barang' => 02,
        'harga' => 100000,
    ]
);
```

I want to join them to form a multidimensional array with subsets of data grouped by `id_barang`, but my code is still wrong.

```
$result=array();
foreach ($barang as $value) {
    foreach ($harga as $k => $val) {
        $result[$value['id_barang'] = $val["id_barang"]] = [
            'harga' => $val["harga"]
        ];
    }
}
echo "<pre>";
echo print_r($result);
```

The output is:

```
Array
(
   [1] => Array
    (
        [harga] => 2000000
    )
   [2] => Array
    (
        [harga] => 100000
    )
)
```

The desired result:

```
Array
(
  [0] => Array
  (
    [id_barang] => 01
    [nama_barang] => laptop
    [merk] => lenovo
    [dataharga] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [id_barang] => 01
                        [harga] => 2000000
                    )
            )
  )
  [1] => Array
  (
    [id_barang] => 02
    [nama_barang] => RAM
    [merk] => lenovo
    [dataharga] => Array
            (
                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [id_barang] => 02
                        [harga] => 100000
                    )
            )
  )
  [2] => Array
  (
    [id_barang] => 03
    [nama_barang] => Keyboard
    [merk] => lenovo
    [dataharga] => Array
            (
                [2] => Array
                    (
                        [id_barang] => ""
                        [harga] => ""
                    )
            )
  )
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following code and see whether it works:

```
$barang=array(
    [
        'id_barang' => 01,
        'nama_barang' => "laptop",
        'merk' => 'lenovo'
    ],
    [
        'id_barang' => 02,
        'nama_barang' => "RAM",
        'merk' => 'lenovo'
    ],
    [
        'id_barang' => 03,
        'nama_barang' => "Keyborad",
        'merk' => 'lenovo'
    ],
);
$harga=array(
    [
        'id_barang' => 01,
        'harga' => 2000000,
    ],
    [
        'id_barang' => 02,
        'harga' => 100000,
    ]
    );


foreach ($barang as &$value) {
    $index =array_search($value['id_barang'], array_column($harga, 'id_barang'));

    if($index > -1) {
      $value['dataharga'] = array($harga[$index]); // Do you really need additional array() ?
    } else {
      $value['dataharga'] = array(['id_barang' => "", 'harga' => ""]); // Do you really need additional array() ?
    }
}

echo "<pre>";
echo print_r($barang);
```

Comment: thanks for the answer sir. that's right code. but I have another problem. how if the data take from a table . should I use foreach for array harga?

Comment: You could convert the table to array or use some other way like `array_search` depending on what type of `$harga` you export from table.

Answer (score 0):

Judging by [your subsequent question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72766818/2943403), I'll recommend a LEFT JOIN and only link the `pj_detailsupplier` table when `id_barang` is not null.

Then use PHP to iterate the rows and group on the `id_barang` value and push "harga" data into the `dataharga` subarray.

Recommended (untested) CodeIgniter code:

```
$rows = $this->db
    ->select('pj_barang.*, pj_detailsupplier.*')
    ->from('pj_barang')
    ->join('pj_detailsupplier', 'pj_barang.id_barang = pj_detailsupplier.id_barang AND pj_barang.id_barang IS NOT NULL', 'LEFT')
    ->where('dihapus', 'tidak')
    ->get()
    ->result_array();

$grouped = [];
foreach ($rows as $row) {
    if (!isset($grouped[$row['id_barang']])) {
        $grouped[$row['id_barang']] = [
            'id_barang' => $row['id_barang'],
            'kode_barang' => $row['kode_barang'],
            'nama_barang' => $row['nama_barang'],
            'total_stok' => $row['total_stok'],
            'harga_beli' => $row['harga_beli'],
            'id_kategori_barang' => $row['id_kategori_barang'],
            'id_merk_barang' => $row['id_merk_barang'],
            'tanggal_expired' => $row['tanggal_expired'],
            'deskripsi' => $row['deskripsi'],
            'gambar' => $row['gambar'],
            'dihapus' => $row['dihapus'],
        ];
    }
    $grouped[$row['id_barang']]['dataharga'][] =  [
        'id_detailsupplier' => $row['id_detailsupplier'],
        'id_supplier' => $row['id_supplier'],
        'no_batch' => $row['no_batch'],
        'stok' => $row['stok'],
        'tanggal' => $row['tanggal'],
        'status_detailsupplier' => $row['status_detailsupplier'],
    ];
}
var_export(array_values($grouped));
// return array_values($grouped));
```

Comment: I have tried the second code just now and the output for data table pj_detailsupplier display all. how if I want to display all data table pj_barang even in colomn id_barang in table pj_detailsupplier empty. because I also need data pj_barang in my aplication sir

Comment: Please remove older comments to keep this page clean.  Is it better if you do not join on null id columns? `->join('pj_detailsupplier', 'pj_barang.id_barang = pj_detailsupplier.id_barang AND pj_barang.id_barang IS NOT NULL', 'LEFT')`

Comment: You have unlocked the privilege to reward me for my advice.

Comment: This should be the adopted answer and I will delete mine.